# Unable to view comments on my website

Tags: comments

I apparently have several comments as the number appearing in the comment section on the dashboard for some reason I can't seem to view the comment.

Comment: Can you let me know where do you are facing the issue

Comment: on the dashboard by the comments tab, I got the number 15 which I guess means I got 15 comments but I don't know how should I view them

Comment: you need to click on comments on the admin panel

Comment: Unfortunately number is showing but still can't access it through the admin panel

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot what you get while clicking on it